# java.net.URLEncoder replaces whitespace with '+' chars

Tags: java, urlencode

I have a Java 1.8 web application in which I need to encode my text.  When I do - it replaces whitespace characters with '+' characters...

"My dog has fleas" becomes "My+dog+has+fleas"

when I do

```
URLEncoder.encode("My dog has fleas", "UTF-8");
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's exactly what URLEncoder is for. What would be the point of using URLEncoder if it didn't encode characters that need to be encoded?

Comment: URL's cannot have whitespace characters. what exactly do you want to do with this URL when you encode it?

Comment: In a URL white spaces should be either `%20` or `+`. Are you expecting white spaces to be `%20` instead of `+`? like `My%20dog%20has%20fleas`?

Comment: Sorry I should have put in more context.  It's not my personal decision to encode.  My app sends messages to another app - and the receiver app won't accept messages unless they are first encoded.  What's happening is that the app that's receiving isn't decoding on the other end.  I'll have to talk to the author of the receiving app.